# Magento Community - tracking when an order failed or has been cancelled

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am trying to find a way to track when an order has  failed or been cancelled by customers in the Magento Community edition. 
Is there an extension that can help with this or can the information be queried in PHP myAdmin?

Thanks,
Aleks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a free `order cancel` [module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/order-cancel-link.html).

That module adds a `cancel` button in the customer account -- AFAIK without that module the user cannot cancel the order from his account.

Extending/customizing that module to log all user-cancelled orders shouldn't be very complex task.